# Why does ffmpeg could only record the first 100 frames of the animation?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using the following Python code to make an animation and want to save it as a video through FFmpeg (in **PyCharm**):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FFMpegWriter

def func():
    for j in range(1, len(t)):
        time = j * 0.01
        print('time:{:2}'.format(time))
        yield time

def animate(data):
    time = data
    ax2.plot(time, time, **{'marker':'o'})
    ax2.set_title('t = {:.2}'.format(time))
    return  ax2

def init():
    ax2.plot(0, 0)
    return ax2

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 50, dt)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=True)
ax2.grid()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate, func, interval=dt*1000, blit=False, init_func=init, repeat=False)

plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
ani.save("movie.mp4", writer=writer)

#plt.show()
```

But when `time` reaches `1.0`, the process stopped but it is supposed to stop when `time` reaches `50.0`. The following picture shows when the process stopped. [The **PyCharm** Run console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PeGm.jpg)
I then check `movie.mp4` and find that the video ends when `time` reaches 1.0.
That is to say, only the first 100 frames of the animation were converted into the `.mp4` file, so I was very confused where did the rest of the frames went?

I tried to run the code through windows cmd but got the same result.
I then uncomment the line `#plt.show()` and found that the process stopped when `time` reaches 50.0 and the animation could be displayed properly but still only the first 100 frames was converted.

I am now very confused about this problem and don't know how to solve it. Appreciated for your help.:)

Comment: What is the windows cmd you tried?

Comment: The name of the python file was `test2.py`, so i tried `python test2.py`.@Gyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I look like `FuncAnimation` is not documented currently:

In `animation.py`, in the class `FuncAnimation(TimedAnimation):`...

There is a line of code:

```
    if self.save_count is None:
        # If we're passed in and using the default, set save_count to 100.
        self.save_count = 100
```

**That's where the `100` frames comes from.**

According to the documentation, `save_count` is the number of frames to cache:

> save_count : int, optional
>          The number of values from *frames* to cache.

It's either a documentation bug, or an implementation bug in `animation.py`.

Setting `save_count` to `5000` records 5000 frames:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate, func, save_count=5000, interval=dt*1000, blit=False, init_func=init, repeat=False)
```

---

- Note there is also a missing `\` in your code: `'C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'`